# CORS - Запрос из постороннего источника заблокирован: Политика одного источника запрещает чтение удаленного ресурса

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

Вот такая ошибка как решить ее:

> Запрос из постороннего источника заблокирован: Политика одного источника запрещает чтение удаленного ресурса на `http://localhost:5000/api/user/registration`. (Причина: не удалось выполнить запрос `CORS`). Код состояния: (`null`).

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cors?tab=Votes

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте поставить `/` в конце запроса.

`http://localhost:5000/api/user/registration/` - вот так

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно на сервере подключить cors. Пример для nest

```js
app.enableCors({
    origin: [
      'http://127.0.0.1:5173',
      'http://127.0.0.1:5000',
      'http://localhost:5173',
      'http://localhost:5000',
      'http://client:5000',
      'http://client'
    ],
    methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS',
    credentials: true,
  });
```